# onClick event doesn't work on nested listview item control in android

Tags: android, listview, android-dialog

I have 2 popups. On the first popup I have `ListView` with selectable items. When I click item from first list, then second popup appear, which also has `ListView` with options to select.

I've implemented first list view items as custom `View` and subscribing to clicks inside view constructor, like that:

```
class CustomListItem extends RelativeLayout{
    public CustomListItem(){
        ...
       //inflating stuff there
       ((Button)findViewById(R.id.listItemButton)).setOnClickListener(
           //This code not working as expected, but then could fire a lot of times
           v -> System.out.println("item clicked");  
       );
    }
}
```

When I open first dialog for the first time `onClick` handler fires as expected and second popup appears. But when I close second popup and return back (calling `Dialog.dismiss()` for popup) to the first popup, then `onClick` handler on first listview stops working. There are some other inetersting things:

1. `onTouch` listener for list view item is still working (called for `action=ACTION_DOWN`
   and `action=ACTION_UP`);
2. when I set for listview `onItemClickListener` it's called always
   (1st time when popup opened and when we return back to it);
3. when I click many times on item in list view sometimes `onClick`
   happens and after that it's called as many times as I clicked
   before.

Do you have any ideas what may be the reason of the problem?

**UPDATE**

Seems that there is a problem with `getView` method inside adapter. I've tried to create a custom list item control inside it (or get it from cache):

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (!constructedViewCache.containsKey(position)) {
        constructedViewCache.put(position, new CustomListItem ());
    }

    return constructedViewCache.get(position);
}
```

When I changed this code to the code below everything works:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (view == null)
    {
       view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_view_item, null);
    }

    view.setOnClickListener(v -> {
         v -> System.out.println("item clicked");
    });

    return view;
}
```

Why it's not possible to create view with a `new CustomListItem ()`? Or if it's possible how should I do that?

Comment: Am I understand correctly, that onclick not properly worked, but if you clicking many times, let's say 20-30 it could fire and after that code for onclick will be executed 20-30 times?

Comment: could you share more code?

Comment: @vovaxo the full code is very complicated. which part of code might be useful for you?

Comment: @silent_coder yes, you are right

Comment: @Natasha Is it depends from the place when you click or did you try click one time and just wait?

Comment: @silent_coder seems it doesn't depend from the place I cliked. I try to wait for quite a long time and handler wasn't called.

Comment: @vovaxo please checkout question update

Comment: @Natasha please check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert the attribute `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` in the parent layout declaration of your list item where `listItemButton` is placed.

Where attribute `android:descendantFocusability`

> Defines the relationship between the ViewGroup and its descendants when looking for a View to take focus.

And constant `blocksDescendants` means that:

> The ViewGroup will block its descendants from receiving focus.

**Second question**

It's possible to create view with a new CustomListItem (). See example below:

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    return new CustomListItem(context);
}
```

**EDIT**

I didn't see your full code, it looks that you are something wrong. Here is working example take a look at:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
private HashMap<Integer, CustomListItem> constructedViewCache = new HashMap<>();

public CustomAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 20;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    if (!constructedViewCache.containsKey(position)) {
        constructedViewCache.put(position, new CustomListItem(context, position));
    }
    return constructedViewCache.get(position);
}
}
```

And second class:

```
public class CustomListItem extends RelativeLayout {
private static final String TAG = "CustomListItem";

public CustomListItem(Context context, int position) {
    super(context);

      View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_view, this);
    Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(view1 -> {
        Log.e(TAG, "CustomListItem: " + position );
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((AppCompatActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager();
        new CustomDialog().show(fragmentManager, "tag");
    });

}
}
```

**EDIT 2**

I've updated `CustomListItem` to display dialog when button is clicked. There is code of custom DialogFragment which is using list of items same layout and adapter as activity:

```
public class CustomDialog extends DialogFragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
    ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(getActivity()));
    return view;
}
}
```

Comment: `android:descendantFocusability` doesn't affect the result but your second suggestion with creating `new CustomListItem()` works normally and doesn't "break" clicks. I still don't understand the reason of the problem: why caching items cause the problem with clicks?

Comment: I've checked your code. I do exactly the same. Have you tried it with dialog? I have the first dialog with list and button which opens another dialog and when we return back from second dialog to the first clicks stop working. Initially they works perfectly (both dialogs fullscreen - not sure if it's important)

Comment: This is strange. Could you share the code with creating dialogs (first and second level)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121949/discussion-between-vovaxo-and-natasha).

Comment: I've checked your answer. I use a `Dialog` class instead of `DialogFragment`. So, that it may be the reason but it doesn't matter now. I've watched this video https://youtu.be/wDBM6wVEO70?t=817 and found that it was not recommended to use item caching inside adapter. There is no guarantee that it will work and we can not rely on it. The only predictable way to work with `getView()` is reusing already created view and initialize it when it's `null`.

Comment: @Natasha Yes you are right. Better to use ViewHolder pattern to improve performance. You may use `RecyclerView` which has built in ViewHolder.